# Java How to iterate through an array of doubles and round to nearest whole number

Tags: java, arrays, rounding

Tried a couple of things. I need to iterate through an array of doubles. And round each element to the nearest whole number. Any ideas where I'm going wrong ?

```
     for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
     Math.round(example[i]);
     }


     int[] example1 = new int[example.length];
     for(int i=0; i<example1.length; i++) {
         Math.round(example1[i]);
         example1[i] = (int) example[i]; 
     }
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `Math.round` back to the aray element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
     Math.round(example[i]);
}
```

In the loop above, you are not assigning the value of `Math.round()` to a variable and hence you lose it.

If you do not need the `double[]`'s values, you can assign it back to the same element. So, you loop would look as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
    example[i] = Math.round(example[i]); // assigning back to same element
}
```

else, put it into a different array, possibly an `int[]`. Then, it would look as follows:

```
int[] roundedValues = new int[example.length];  
for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
        roundedValues[i] = (int) Math.round(example[i]); // into new array
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun And I did that =)

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign Math.round to a variable.

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
    example[i] =  Math.round(example[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++){
      example[i] = Math.round(example[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 loops.

You are not using the result returned from `Math.round()`.

You are trying to cast a double to an int - no need to do that.

Try:

```
double[] exmaple = //get your array of doubles
long[] rounded = new long[example.length];

for (int i=0; i<example.length; i++) {
  rounded[i] = Math.round(example[i]);
}
```